# EmberJS - How to display subset of a model in a view

Tags: ember.js

I am very new (started today) to Ember and cannot figure how how to set this up in a correct manner.

Models:

Post, Comment

On the 'show' template for Post, I want to display only the comments that are not blocked (isBlocked is a attribute of Comment model).  Should I use a View and pass in a param to filter out the comments?

I cannot find an useful example or tutorial that explains this.  Is there a way similar to how this would be done in Rails with partials and locals or something?

Comment: can you post the relevant code route/controller/model etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a computed property that uses `filterProperty` to filter your model inside your controller. Then use that computed property to display in your template.

Assuming your `Comment` model has an `isBlocked` attribute, you can set up a computed property like,

```
comments: function() {
  return this.filterProperty('isBlocked', false);
}.property('@each.isBlocked')
```

Then in the template use `comments` as the collection to iterate over. The comments collection will have all comments except those where `isBlocked` is true.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I ask one more question?  Is there a way I can make this dynamic?  For example, pass in a value I want to filter the model with?

Comment: Sure, You can lookup other instance variables within the `comments` function with `this.get`. For more complex filtering, use `.filter` where you pass a callback function that does manual filtering by looking at multiple properties, etc.